# Opening a html link to read a PDF file on browser is blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, html

I can't open a PDF at a tab in a browser from a html link.

```
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Problem:

[image]

But, if I open the link directly on the browser (https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf), that will open in the browser without any issue.

How to solve this?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dg02pk78/1/)

Comment: You Fiddle works just fine for me. Turn off your ad blocker.

Comment: I have turned off adblocker; still the issue exist in my chrome

Comment: Test in a private window, with all extensions disabled. Still same problem?

Comment: I have the same in my chrome - even after I remove the adblocker for w3org

Comment: Problem still exist in private window. I have even tried with removing target="_blank". Here is the recording: https://imgur.com/KEfzzqe

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, when I try directly from within your fiddle - but not when I put the same link into a different page, that doesn't use sandboxed iframes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around it with a proxy script (on the same domain):

### PHP example

Save code below as `test.php`, and start server with `php -S localhost:1234 test.php`. Go to `http://localhost:1234`.

```php
if(isset($_GET['url']) && strpos($_GET['url'],"http") > -1) {
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    exit;
}
?>

<a href="?url=https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

### Update; pure javascript version

With this code you can download the pdf through a proxy (api.allorigins.win) which avoids Same-origin policy problems.

After that the pdf is saved with window.URL.createObjectURL and opened in a new window.

```html
<script>
function loadPdf(url)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url), true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200){
            var blob=new Blob([req.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.target = "_blank";
            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.click();
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:loadPdf('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');">PDF</a>
```

Comment: I am not allowed to implement PHP in my working project. I can apply any javascript solution in maximum.

Comment: I have added a pure javascript version.